# Condition for custom upsert in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I use Elasticsearch 6.8.13 and Java SDK for elasticsearch. I try to make custom upsert. The idea is to use Painless script for make a decision to index document or nothing to do.

I tried next Painless script:

```
if (condition) {
    ctx.op = 'noop';
} else {
    ctx._source.field1 = params.field1;
    ctx._source.field2 = params.field2;
}
```

and next Java code:

```
private UpdateRequest createUpsertRequest(Map<String, Object> params) {
        return new UpdateRequest(elasticProperties.getIndex(), "_doc", params.get(DOCUMENT_ID_KEY).toString())
    .script(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", UPSERT_SCRIPT, params))
    .upsert(params);
}
```

The code above works well for me, but I want to make only decision to upsert or not inside Painless script and delegate source property mapping to Java SDK. For example:

```
if (condition) {
    ctx.op = 'noop';
} else {
    ctx.op = 'index';   
}
```

In this example I get UpdateResponse with result 'UPDATE' but document fields weren't updated

Is there any way make this work?